# Invalid instance in App.root

Tags: python, изображения, kivy

Решил добавить в приложение **Image**, дает сбой, может это происходит не из-за изображения, но других предположений по этому поводу не возникает

```
from kivy.core.image import Image
from kivy.app import App

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        img = Image("nature.png",size_hint=(5,10),pos_hint={'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5})
        return img

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

вот, что пишет консоль

```
[CRITICAL] App.root must be an _instance_ of Widget
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\User\Desktop\Projects\school\Raspisanie.py", line 
32, in <module>
 MainApp().run()
 File 
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\app.py", line 954, in run
self._run_prepare()
File 
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\kivy\app.py", line 930, in _run_prepare
raise Exception('Invalid instance in App.root')
Exception: Invalid instance in App.root
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замени

```
from kivy.core.image import Image
```

на

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image # uix вместо core
```

и

```
img = Image("nature.png",size_hint=(5,10),pos_hint={'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5})
```

на

```
img = Image(source="nature.png", size_hint=(5,10), pos_hint={'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5})
# добавлено source=
```

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало!